# page visit and duration for each user id in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Connected python with google analytics, trying to pull raw data for each user-id, which page it has visited and how long spent on it. Test code from website look like this, i am lost on how to update this code.

the official metric website doesn't seem even have a col named user-id ...
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet

```
{
  "reportRequests":
  [
    {
      "viewId": "XXXX",
      "dateRanges":
      [
        {"endDate": "2014-11-30", "startDate": "2014-11-01"}
      ],
      "metrics":
      [
        {"expression": "ga:users"}
      ],
      "dimensions":
      [
        {"name": "ga:city"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dimension for user identification available through API. If you have GA360 and enabled the [BigQuery integration](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618?hl=en), you can extract clientId / userId level information by querying the tables in BigQuery. According to [this guide](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089)

> When you initially link an Analytics reporting view to BigQuery,
> Analytics exports 13 months or 10 billion hits (whichever is smaller)
> of historical data to BigQuery.

Another solution is to [create a Custom Dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en) of user scope and [pass clientId with it in Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets#send-custom-dimensions). Then using API, you will able to fetch the required information.

Comment: thank you for response @dikesh. If we never set bigquery before, is it too late now to set it up to query data from 3,6,12 months ago? Same to custom dimension, is it now too late to set up for historical info?

Comment: also @dikesh , do you have some instruction how to do this?'create a Custom Dimension of user scope and pass clientId with it in Google Analytics'

Comment: thank you @dikesh, just to confirm. if i set the custom dimension now. it will only information starting the point it's created correct? 
also, it sounds like it needs experienced developer to set up the final step, not by newbie like me...correct?

Quote: 'After you create custom dimensions or metrics in your property, you must also modify your tracking code. This should be completed by a qualified developer. Follow the instructions in the Developer Guide for your specific environment:'

Comment: Yes, there is no backfill for custom dimension. Also, feel free to upvote or mark the answer as accepted.